# R Shiny: conditionalPanel sharing sidebars on select panels

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm trying to display reactive plots on different panels. Some of them are based on the same inputs, which come from sliders on the sidebar. I want to conserve the same slider (and inputs) between these panels. In other panels, I want unique conditional inputs. Here is an example:

```
##server
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$scatterPlotA <- renderPlot({
    x <- rnorm(input$slider1)
    y <- rnorm(input$slider1)
    plot(x, y)
  })
   output$scatterPlotB <- renderPlot({
    x <- rnorm(input$slider2)
    y <- rnorm(input$slider2)
    plot(x, y)
  })
     output$scatterPlotC <- renderPlot({
    x <- rnorm(input$slider2)
    y <- rnorm(input$slider2)
    plot(x, y,col="red")
  })
})
```

This ui conserves the slider between panels 2-3, but it won't control 3.

```
##ui
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Conditional Panels"),
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==1",
                     helpText("Content Panel 1"),
                     sliderInput("slider1", "Number of points: S1", min = 10, max = 200, value = 50, step = 10)

    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2",
                     helpText("Content Panel 2"),
                     sliderInput("slider2", "Number of points: S2", min = 10, max = 200, value = 50, step = 10)            
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==3",
                     helpText("Content Panel 2"),
                     sliderInput("slider2", "Number of points: S2", min = 10, max = 200, value = 50, step = 10)            
    ) 
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Panel 1", value=1, 
      plotOutput("scatterPlotA", height = 300)),
      tabPanel("Panel 2", value=2,
      plotOutput("scatterPlotB", height = 300)),
       tabPanel("Panel 3", value=3,
      plotOutput("scatterPlotC", height = 300)),
      id = "conditionedPanels"
    )
  )
))
```

This ui does what I want EXCEPT that the slider from panel 2 ends up on panel 1.

```
##ui
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Conditional Panels"),
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==1",
                     helpText("Content Panel 1"),
                     sliderInput("slider1", "Number of points: S1", min = 10, max = 200, value = 50, step = 10)

    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2||3",
                     helpText("Content Panel 2"),
                     sliderInput("slider2", "Number of points: S2", min = 10, max = 200, value = 50, step = 10)            
    ) 
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Panel 1", value=1, 
      plotOutput("scatterPlotA", height = 300)),
      tabPanel("Panel 2", value=2,
      plotOutput("scatterPlotB", height = 300)),
       tabPanel("Panel 3", value=3,
      plotOutput("scatterPlotC", height = 300)),
      id = "conditionedPanels"
    )
  )
))
```

Any guidance for sharing some sidebars between panels while making others unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first `ui.R` is that you are still defining three different sliders.  What you really want is for the second slider to appear under either of two conditions.  So change the condition for the second slider to reflect that logic, and get rid of the third slider.  The following code worked for me.

```
sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==1",
                     helpText("Content Panel 1"),
                     sliderInput("slider1", "Number of points: S1", min = 10, max = 200, value = 50, step = 10)

    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.conditionedPanels==2 || input.conditionedPanels==3",
                     helpText("Content Panel 2"),
                     sliderInput("slider2", "Number of points: S2", min = 10, max = 200, value = 50, step = 10)            
    ) 
  ),
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated Paul.